Compute the normal bundle of the cartesian product of two smooth subvarieties over the cartesian product of 2 bigger varieties.
Let $X$ be a smooth projective subvariety of $Y$ a smooth projective variety and $\mathcal{N}_{X/Y}$ the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$. I am having a hard time proving that the normal bundle of $ X \times \{P\} $ in $ Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ is isomorphic to $$\mathcal{N}_{X/Y}\bigoplus \mathcal{O}_X ,$$
with $\mathcal{O}_X$ being the structure sheaf of $X$ and $P=[0:1]$.
As a general approach one should look at a global section of a vector bundle in $ Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ whose zero locus is precisely  $ X \times \{P\} $ but I simply can't figure out the way to do it in order to get the above result. Any idea or intuition of the proof will be highly welcome.

What is your definition of the normal bundle?

Dear @Daniel a normal bundle here is viewed as in the algebraic geometry setting that means that for a closed immersion of projective varieties $ X \subset Y$ one considers the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$ being the pull back of the tangent bundle of Y via the inclusion map quotient out by the tangent bunble of $X$,  namely $i^{\star}T_Y/ T_X$.

From the chain of closed embeddings $ X \times \{ P \} \subset Y \times \{ P \} \subset Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ there is an exact sequence (1) of normal bundles \begin{equation} 0 \rightarrow N_{X \times \{P \} / Y \times \{ P \}} = N_{X/Y} \rightarrow N_{X \times \{P \} / Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 } \rightarrow (N_{Y \times \{ P \} / Y \times \mathbb{P}^1})|_{X \times \{ P \}} = \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow 0 \end{equation}
From another chain of closed embeddings $ X \times \{ P \} \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^1 \subset Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ we get an injection (2) $$ 0 \rightarrow N_{X \times \{ P \} / X \times \mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow N_{X \times \{P \} / Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 } $$
The composition $$ \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow N_{X \times \{P \} / Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 } \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X $$ is not zero because if it was, then $ \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow N_{X \times \{P \} / Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 } $ would factor through $ N_{X/Y} $, a contradiction as the normal vectors in $ N_{X \times \{ P \} / X \times \mathbb{P}^1} $ are vertical. So the composition is an isomorphism because $ X $ is a projective variety i.e. (2) is a splitting for (1).

Hi @CraniumClamp thank you for your contribution. However, I would emit some major concern regarding your proof attempt. In fact I notice first hand that although it seems counterintuitive the rank of $\mathcal{N}{X \times {P}/Y \times {P} }$ is always strictly bigger than that of $\mathcal{N}{X/Y}$ which means that the two are neither isomorphic nor equal.

What? $ X \times P$ is isomorphic to $ X $…

isomorphism doesn't always translate very well in term of sheaf and the likes. For instance for $X$ being the locus of a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in $Y= \mathbb{P}^2$ we will have $\mathcal{N}{X/Y} \cong \mathcal {O}X(d)$, however $\mathcal{N}{X \times P/Y\times P} \cong \mathcal{N}{X/Y} \bigoplus \mathcal{O}_X $.

Whatever you’re saying is plain incorrect.
